# Ploting and saving figures in node js with gnuplot

Tags: node.js, gnuplot, child-process

I'm using gnuplot in a bash child process in node js to plot some data and save the figure. This is my code so far:

```
var term = require('child_process').spawn('bash');
term.stdin.write('gnuplot -p\n');
term.stdin.write('set key outside\n');
term.stdin.write('set term png\n');
term.stdin.write('set output "plot1.png"\n')
term.stdin.write('plot for [col=2:4] "results" using 1:col with points title columnheader\n');
term.stdin.write('set output "plot2.png"\n')
term.stdin.write('plot for [col=5:7] "results" using 1:col with points title columnheader\n');
```

Is this the more correct and fastest way of doing this? there's anyway I can make it more compact and simple? Also, when I run this inside my node.js script the the child won't exit when I run the script so the script won't exit. How can solve this?

Comment: did you add term.stdin.write('exit\n') ? this will cause gnuplot to close and to close the output file

Comment: that doesn't work @bibi

Comment: does all the write return true? don't know the -p flag if it is appropriate

Comment: also that desn't make any difference, all the write comes true

Comment: a couple of questions: why don't you spawn gnuplot directly? what is the porpouse of the -p flag in gnuplot? shouldn/y you issue 2 exits (one for gnuplot and one for bash)?

Comment: Solved! Thanks @bibi. the -p flag had no effect. Gnuplot could bespawned be directly and term.stdin.write('exit\n') had the effect it should have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

spawn gnuplot directly `var term = require('child_process').spawn('gnuplot');` instead of the bash.

remove `term.stdin.write('gnuplot -p\n');` (-p flag makes gnuplot windows persistent, but there's no need for this because in this case plots are printed to png images)

add `term.stdin.write('exit\n')` at the end.